# Does bone resorption cause alkalosis?

Tags: bone-biology, homeostasis

The phosphate in hydroxyapatite Ca5(PO4)3(OH) is a strong base, PO4^3-, and the hydroxide is also a base, OH-. I was talking with a biologist the other day about if bone resorption (at a level that causes elevated calcium and phosphate) also causes alkalosis. He did not think so, but mentioned that it might be buffered or compensated for. In general, does bone resorption cause alkalosis?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but Metabolic alkalosis decreases bone calcium (in general).